# SQLLOADER :: How to add expressions to CLOB columns in SQLLOADER Control file

Tags: sql, loader, clob, sql-loader

Our requirement is , We need to import a csv file to DB tables using SQL*Loader

Current Use case:

1) we have a default value for a CLOB column (For Ex : '1234')
2) In our Input file, we have some column values  that are empty.

For Ex :

```
Name(varchar)    Value(clob)

       a1               clob1
       a2
       a3               clob3
```

3) Our control file should be such that, when imported above csv using SQL-LOADER, our data in DB should be as below

```
Name           Value

   a1              clob1
   a2              1234
   a3              clob3
```

How can we achieve this? what expression can we keep for this `CLOB` field in SQLLOADER control file?

As of now, we have this in the control file:

```
        ATTRIBUTE_CLOB001         CHAR DEFAULTIF "ATTRIBUTE_CLOB001"='#NULL' NULLIF "ATTRIBUTE_CLOB001"=BLANKS,
```

I read SQL strings are not supported on CLOB.(http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a67792/ch03.htm#8441 - check 'New SQL*Loader DDL Behavior and Restrictions')

Is there any SQL*Loader specific expressions/procedure to achieve this?

Comment: when we add SQL expressions in control file, we are getting error when sqlloader is getting executed. Nothing is mentioned in latest doc(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_loading.htm#g1026656)

Comment: What is the expression you tried, and what is the error?  Help us help you!

Comment: This is what we tried :: ATTRIBUTE_CLOB001   "Case when :ATTRIBUTE_CLOB001 is not null then (case when :ATTRIBUTE_CLOB001 = '#NULL' then (select chr(0) from dual) else :ATTRIBUTE_CLOB001 end) else '1234' end"

Comment: Error observed is : SQL*Loader-309: No SQL string allowed as part of ATTRIBUTE_CLOB001 field specification